# vertical and horizontal reference line in d3.js chart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am trying to draw vertical and horizontal reference line in my scatter plot below is my code for that

```
var dataSum = d3.sum(data, function(d) {
  return d.volume;
})

var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d, i) {
    return x2(d.volume) + 10;
  })
  .y(function(d, i) {
    return yScale(20);
  });

/* Horizontal line */
svg.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("d", line)
  .attr("class", "refline")
  .style("fill", "none");
/* vertical line */
svg.append("svg:line")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("x1", 266)
  .attr("y1", 10)
  .attr("x2", 266)
  .attr("y2", 350)
  .attr("class", "refline")

/* class */
.refline {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #2F4F4F;
        stroke-width: 1.0px;
        stroke-dasharray: 5,15;
    }
```

vertical line draws as expected, but horizontal line is not showing the line dashed like the class `refline` says it should, Is there any other better way of drawing these lines?

[image]

Comment: Looks like your line is drawing fine in the (very small) image. Could you please provide an example of your problem in jsfiddle or plunkr?

Comment: problem is with Horizontal line as you can see in the image, stroke dash array is not working.., here is the code in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/h1y2t96z/

Comment: 1. Your jsfiddle doesn't work. 2. the path does get the dasharray: https://jsfiddle.net/vhkr1fse/. I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion as @GerardoFurtado, https://jsfiddle.net/dp7ntb7o/8/. you should provide more detail as to what your data is for example. btw, your horizontal line seems to have a larger width than 1.0px. voting to close also.